# Fusion Tables + Google Maps + marker overlapping

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I´m using Fusion Tables with thousand of markers but in several locations i´ve thousand of markers in a small place (ex: street block with 4000 markers), but the markers are not overlapping when zooming in..it looks like that Google organize the markers in order not be on top of each others.

Image of the issue..
http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/7267/70124074.png

Anyway to fix this using Fusion+Google Maps API?

Thanks.